# NSIS: How to add custom button to left bottom corner and handle it's click?

Tags: nsis

I tried the ButtonEvent plugin, but when I run compiled example, it fails with memory access error. Maybe it is able to do with System plugin via Windows API or something else? Can anyone show how it can be done?

**UPD: Error was appeared because I tried to use non-unicode ButtonEvent on Unicode NSIS. Now example compiles and executes OK, but when I click on TryMe button, callback function is not called and nothing happens. How to determine what is the problem? Can anyone compile ButtonEventMUI.nsi and click on TryMe button? I downloaded latest ButtonEvent version. Using NSIS 2.46 Unicode**

Comment: Maybe you could add some more details: NSIS version (Unicode?) and plugin version/date...

Comment: There was a crashfix ( http://forums.winamp.com/showpost.php?p=2769430&postcount=11 ) in 2011 so make sure your plugin is up-to-date.

Comment: I use latest ButtonEvent Unicode and NSIS 2.46 Unicode. I updated my question, thanks for hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system plugin cannot do this because it cannot subclass windows.

The ButtonEvent plugin works fine for me (NSIS 2.46):

```
Name BtnTest
Outfile test.exe
Installdir "$temp"
RequestExecutionLevel user
BrandingText " " ;Button covers this text
!include nsDialogs.nsh ;For WS_*

Function .onGuiInit
; You are supposed to use ChangeUI (or MUI_UI) and a modified ui file to add new buttons but this example adds the button at run-time...
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 2 ; Find cancel button
System::Call *(i,i,i,i)i.r1
System::Call 'USER32::GetWindowRect(ir0,ir1)'
System::Call *$1(i.r2,i.r3,i.r4,i.r5)
IntOp $5 $5 - $3 ;height
IntOp $4 $4 - $2 ;width
System::Call 'USER32::ScreenToClient(i$hwndparent,ir1)'
System::Call *$1(i.r2,i.r3)
System::Free $1
IntOp $2 $2 + $4 ;x
IntOp $2 $2 + 8  ;x+padding
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0,t "Button",t "Click Me",i${WS_CHILD}|${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_TABSTOP},ir2,ir3,ir4,ir5,i $hwndparent,i 0x666,i0,i0)i.r0'
SendMessage $hwndparent ${WM_GETFONT} 0 0 $1
SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETFONT} $1 1

GetFunctionAddress $0 onmybtnclick
ButtonEvent::AddEventHandler 0x666 $0
FunctionEnd

Function onmybtnclick
MessageBox mb_ok "You clicked me!"
FunctionEnd

Page Directory
Page Instfiles

Section
SectionEnd
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Rename .onGuiInit to myGuiInit and !define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT myGuiInit at the top of your script

Comment: Hmm, when I click your button nothing is happen.. When I compile ButtonEvent example nothing is happen too. I think problem is in my configuration. But I even don't know where to start searching from..

Comment: Try to debug your script by adding some message boxes - on $0 before GetFunctionAddress $0 onmybtnclick.