# How to add a link on the lower zone, near the Back/Next buttons

Tags: nsis

I would like to add a link to our company's website on the lower left corner of the installer window, but don't know how to do it since it's out of the editable area (I use NSIS Dialog Designer to design our custom pages):

[image]

I found how to add a button [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443620/nsis-how-to-add-custom-button-to-left-bottom-corner-and-handle-its-click), but I need a link.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example uses the [Linker plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Linker_plug-in) to transform the brandingtext label to a link control. If you need both brandingtext and a URL you need to add another label with Resource Hacker + `ChangeUI` or add it at run-time by using `System::Call user32::CreateWindowEx(...)`

```
BrandingText /TRIMRIGHT "Visit our homepage"

Function .onGuiInit
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 0x404
EnableWindow $0 1 ; Branding text control is usually disabled
Linker::link /NOUNLOAD $0 "http://www.example.com/"
FunctionEnd

Function .onGuiEnd
Linker::unload
FunctionEnd

Page Components
Page Instfiles

Section
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but the link must be positioned as in the image I just uploaded. I'll try to use `System::Call user32::CreateWindowEx(...)` but I'm not a Windows programmer so it scares me a bit. :)

Comment: What about the button that is usually located there?

Comment: In my installer, the 3 buttons (Back, Next and Cancel) are located to the right. Maybe it's because I use MUI 2? Also, I would like to keep them where they are.