# How to close a custom window after button click event - nsis

Tags: nsis

I have the below code:

```
Function fnc_custom_page
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 2 ; Find cancel button
System::Call *(i,i,i,i)i.r1
System::Call 'USER32::GetWindowRect(ir0,ir1)'
System::Call *$1(i.r2,i.r3,i.r4,i.r5)
IntOp $5 $5 - $3 ;height
IntOp $4 $4 - $2 ;width
IntOp $4 $4 + 50
System::Call 'USER32::ScreenToClient(i$HWNDPARENT,ir1)'
System::Call *$1(i.r2,i.r3)
System::Free $1
IntOp $2 $2 - $4 ;x
IntOp $2 $2 - 8  ;x+padding
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0,t "Button",t "Open tch",i${WS_CHILD}|${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_TABSTOP},ir2,ir3,ir4,ir5,i $HWNDPARENT,i 0x666,i0,i0)i.r0'
SendMessage $HWNDPARENT ${WM_GETFONT} 0 0 $1
SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETFONT} $1 1
GetFunctionAddress $R0 fnc_tch
ButtonEvent::AddEventHandler 0x666 $R0

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function fnc_tch
Exec "$INSTDIT\tch.exe" 
Abort
FunctionEnd
```

I have only one page, and I do not want to show any thing else. If I click open tch, tch.exe should run and installer should exit; but I am not able to make installer exit.
Any input please.

Source for above code: [NSIS: How to add custom button to left bottom corner and handle it's click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443620/nsis-how-to-add-custom-button-to-left-bottom-corner-and-handle-its-click)

Comment: I do not think it is good idea but I have used taskkill to kill the installer after it has done the job that I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time you can use `Quit` but plugin related callback functions do not handle it (The quit flag is not a part of the plugin API).

The alternative is to emulate a click on the close button:

```
!include WinMessages.nsh
SendMessage $HwndParent ${WM_CLOSE} 0 0
```