# Skip page on added button clicked

Tags: nsis

I have this added button from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443620/nsis-how-to-add-custom-button-to-left-bottom-corner-and-handle-its-click):

```
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 2 ; Find cancel button
System::Call *(i,i,i,i)i.r1
System::Call 'USER32::GetWindowRect(ir0,ir1)'
System::Call *$1(i.r2,i.r3,i.r4,i.r5)
IntOp $5 $5 - $3 ;height
IntOp $4 $4 - $2 ;width
System::Call 'USER32::ScreenToClient(i$hwndparent,ir1)'
System::Call *$1(i.r2,i.r3)
System::Free $1
IntOp $2 $2 + $4 ;x
IntOp $2 $2 + 8  ;x+padding
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0,t "Button",t "Skip",i${WS_CHILD}|${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_TABSTOP},i 170,i 327,ir4,ir5,i $hwndparent,i 0x666,i0,i0)i.r0'
SendMessage $hwndparent ${WM_GETFONT} 0 0 $1
SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETFONT} $1 1

GetFunctionAddress $0 onmybtnclick
ButtonEvent::AddEventHandler 0x666 $0
```

I put this in a custom page function, and I placed it to be displayed like this:
[image: skip button]
And everything is working perfectly, except for I want this button functions as a Skip to the next custom page I have in order.
I tried to get the window and send a NEXT command to it, tried to call the custom page function and even tried global labels from [this url](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/Call), and I tried to call `Abort` from almost every line of code it reaches.
I'm still missing something and google results went all purple. I need a way to jump to next page based on a click and this button must be besides `Back` button.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> The pre-function allows you to skip the page using Abort.

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Page Custom Page1
Page Custom Page2
Page Directory
Page InstFiles

Var SkipPage2

Function onmybtnclick
StrCpy $SkipPage2 1 ; Set flag so the next page knows to skip itself 
SendMessage $HWNDPARENT ${WM_COMMAND} 1 0 ; Click next button
FunctionEnd

Function Page1
    StrCpy $SkipPage2 0 ; Reset
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $0

    ${NSD_CreateButton} 0 30u 100% 10u "&Skip next page"
    Pop $0
    ${NSD_OnClick} $0 onmybtnclick
    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function Page2
${If} $SkipPage2 <> 0
    Abort
${EndIf}
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "I was not skipped"
Pop $0
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```